# Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. (Network controller) not working, probably because of missing drivers

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

when I run `sudo lshw -C network` this is what it outputs:

```
      *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcf00000-fcffffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: a
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: wlx502b73e6c2e2
       serial: 50:2b:73:e6:c2:e2
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7601u driverversion=5.15.0-52-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.203 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

I have tried https://linux-hardware.org/ and it seems they do not have any drivers for this thing. Device data from there:

```
Class   02-80 »
Type    net/wireless »
Vendor  Realtek Semiconductor »
Name    Realtek Network controller
Subsystem   Hewlett-Packard
```

[list of people that have this and have checked their hardware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpTcb.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.